# SQL - Convert a row of id with a name affiliate to this id on an other table

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a request to transforme my row with the name affiliate in an other table.

So there are two table.

Here is the first when we
`SELECT idUser FROM table1`

[image]

Here is the second table when make :
`SELECT id, name FROM user`

[image]

I want make a request to transforme id of first table to name of second

To make this I think we have to :

1. split into columns each row
2. then make a JOIN.
3. Then concat row transform

I'm blocking into the first step.
I think I have to use function but I m not good with it.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please share your table schema